# flexbox parameter issue in Compass

Tags: compass-sass, compass

I am getting `Mixin flexbox doesn't have an argument named $version` in the following code. I have Compass 1.0.1 installed.

```
@import "compass/css3/flexbox";

@mixin all-spec-display-flex() {
    @include flexbox((display: box, flex-direction: row), $version: 1);
    @include flexbox((display: flexbox, flex-direction: row), $version: 2);
    @include flexbox((display: box, flex-direction: row));
}
```

I opened the _flexbox.scss file in Compass and I do see the `$version` param there.

Comment: You need to pass `$version` as a parameter to `all-spec-display-flex()`.

Comment: I am setting `$version` value. I do not need that value to be passed as param.

Comment: Ok. It seems I have another module which also declares a mixin with this same name. Now I am in a pickle. How do I tell Compass which version to pick?